# Switch Case is throwing error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, switch-statement

Below is the code:

```
function addMethods(statusId) {
    var methods = {};
    if (typeof currentUser !== 'undefined') {
        if (currentUser.isAdmin) {
            switch(statusId) {
                case "A":
                    methods.deactivate = true;
                    methods.delete = true;
                    methods.edit = true;
                    break;
                case "P":
                    methods.activate = true;
                    methods.deactivate = true;
                    methods.delete = true;
                    methods.edit = true;
                    break;
                case "D":
                    methods.activate = true;
                    methods.deactivate = true;
                    break;
                case "I":
                    methods.activate = true;
                    methods.delete = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else if (currentUser.userBelongsToCompany) {
            switch(statusId) {
                case "A":
                    methods.deactivate = true;
                    break;
                case "P":
                    methods.activate = true;
                    methods.deactivate = true;
                    methods.edit = true;
                    break;
                case "I":
                    methods.activate = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return methods;
}
```

The error:

```
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
```

Strangely, the error is thrown when it tried to update methods.delete:

```
function addMethods(statusId) {
    var methods = {};
    if (typeof currentUser !== 'undefined') {
        if (currentUser.isAdmin) {
            switch(statusId) {
                case "A":
                    methods.deactivate = true;
                    methods.delete = true;
```

Comment: What version of IE? Should work fine in IE9+

Comment: i tried on ie8-10, all throwing the same error.

Comment: Are you in standards mode, or quirks mode?

Comment: works for >ie8 for me, but , yer better to stay away from the reserved words, why give yourself the pain : ) .remove

Comment: i meant to say is i tried it in IE10, but using document mode and browser mode ie8-ie10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the keyword "delete" as a property name, and that's not really valid (in some JavaScript environments).  You can code it like this however:

```
    methods["delete"] = true;
```

Comment: it's only happening in ie, ff and chrome has no issues.. i will just name it something else then. thanks!

Comment: It's valid in ECMAScript 5.

Comment: @cookiemonster yes that's certainly true.

Answer (score 1):

`delete` is new reserved keywords in JavaScript and should not be used as an identifier. rename it to something else

However you can use bracket notation like

```
methods["delete"] = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

"delete" is a reserved keyword you should rename it.

If you use something like http://www.jshint.com/ it will help identify errors and syntax issues.

Comment: very nice, i will use that site more from now on.

Answer (score 1):

"delete" is a reserved keyword in most of language, in this case you should use

```
methods['delete'] = true;
```

or you can rename you function of "delete".